# Difference between Vertex Array Object and Buffer Object?

Tags: opengl

I'm just starting programming in OpenGL (v. 3.3), and I'm confused as to what exactly these two "objects" are as well as how to use them properly.

For example, say I want to draw two objects to the screen - a sphere and a cube. Should I create two VAOs and two buffer objects - one for each, or should I create one VAO and two buffer objects (with a call to `glBindBuffer()` in between), or create one VAO and one buffer object and call `glBufferData()` to update the buffer object in between draw calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since you have only static geometries, for optimal performance you should really avoid updating any buffer data between draw calls and use only static buffer objects (one for the sphere and one for the cube, or a single one holding both data).

Second, vertex array objects capture the buffer objects that are currently bound, so you would need to either keep two vertex array objects corresponding to two buffer objects (one for the sphere and one for the cube) or use a single one if the data for the sphere and the cube have been merged in a single buffer object. In the latter case, the parameters of `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements` would allow you to select either the sphere or the cube data (or both could be drawn with a single draw call).

Comment: what is a "vertex object"? Is that the same thing as a vertex array?

Comment: @MichaelHagar I meant buffer object instead.